# concurrent.futures is not multithreading as expected

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to execute a cpu-bound procedure several times and I want to distribute its execution over all the 12 cores on my machine.  In my trial example here, the exec time is not reduced, inferring that multithreading has not occurred.  What am I doing wrong?  (I'm on windows10 python3.8)

```
import time, random
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def timer():
    # Start the timer
    start = time.time()
    yield
    # End the timer
    end = time.time()
    # Tell the user how much time elapsed
    print(f"This code block executed in {round(end - start, 3)} seconds.")

def burncpu():
    for i in range(100000):
        x = random.gauss(0, 1)

with timer():
    for index, _ in enumerate(range(100), 1):
        burncpu()
        
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
print(f'I have {cpu_count()} cores available.')

import concurrent.futures as cf
# multithread test to use all the cores on my machine                
with timer():
    # Initiate a pool
    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as tpe:
        for index, _ in enumerate(range(100), 1):
            tpe.submit(burncpu())
```

Output:
This code block executed in 4.556 seconds.
I have 12 cores available.
This code block executed in 4.921 seconds.

Comment: If you want to run something CPU bound, you probably want to try out multiprocessing instead of threading

Comment: You call "burncpu" and submit the result (which is useless). Remove parentheses aftet "burncpu".

Comment: Thankyou for your comments.  I had the perhaps mistaken idea that multithreading/multiprocessing were appropriate for cpu-bound/io-bound operations.    But when I rerun my code with ProcessPool instead if ThreadPool, the time increases to 9.8s !

Comment: Both multithreading and multiprocessing are appropriate for io-bound operations. Multithreading is *not* appropriate for cpu-bound operations.

Comment: You should give callable object to submit method like `tpe.submit(burncpu)` if you want parallelize your task

Comment: I have already removed the () as suggested earlier.